# Is it possible to generate one war file from multiple microservices(Spring Boot)?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven-3, microservices

I have four micro services as below(names changed),

1. Account Service
2. Product Catalog Service
3. Car Service
4. Order Service

However, while developing I am feeling difficulty in starting/deploying all the application.

Also there is a strong reason to do this. Our client has already purchased Weblogic 12c Enterprise Edition. He is reluctant to pay for infrastructure cost incur for deploying microservices. He wants us to follow Monolithic architecture and configure the cluster for the better performance.

Is there a way to put all above micro services(jars) into a war so that we deploy single war?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that But Its look like you are moving away from the `microservice` architecture

You can create new Spring boot application and add all microservice dependency into new application.

Take care below point as well

1. You have to update `@ComponentScan(basePackages =`
2. If you are using JPA repository then you have to update `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages=`